# How do I transpose similar record values into separate columns in R with (reshape2 or etc)?

Tags: r, tidyr, reshape2

So I would like to transform the following:

```
days <- c("MONDAY", "SUNDAY", "MONDAY", "SUNDAY", "MONDAY", "SUNDAY")
dates <- c("2020-03-02", "2020-03-08", "2020-03-09", "2020-03-15", "2020-03-16", "2020-03-22")

df <- cbind(days, dates)


+--------+------------+
|  days  |   dates    |
+--------+------------+
| MONDAY | 2020.03.02 |
| SUNDAY | 2020.03.08 |
| MONDAY | 2020.03.09 |
| SUNDAY | 2020.03.15 |
| MONDAY | 2020.03.16 |
| SUNDAY | 2020.03.22 |
+--------+------------+
```

Into this:

```
+------------+------------+
|   MONDAY   |   SUNDAY   |
+------------+------------+
| 2020.03.02 | 2020.03.08 |
| 2020.03.09 | 2020.03.15 |
| 2020.03.16 | 2020.03.22 |
+------------+------------+
```

Do you have any hints how should I do it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Given that `df` is a dataframe (and not a matrix like in your example) you can do: `df <- data.frame(days, dates); unstack(df, dates ~ days)`

Comment: A reason you may have found this difficult to do with tidyr/reshape2 is, that the transformation is nonsensical from a tidy data perspective. In tidy data, rows represent related data. In your output table, Monday and Sunday looks like two unrelated columns. If you want to go with a tidy approach, you need some way to identify which dates are related and should be in one row.

Comment: that unstack thingy nearly works but that is true that I would need them paired together in a DF. 

Is there a trick to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In Base-R

```
sapply(split(df,df$days), function(x) x$dates)

     MONDAY       SUNDAY      
[1,] "2020-03-02" "2020-03-08"
[2,] "2020-03-09" "2020-03-15"
[3,] "2020-03-16" "2020-03-22"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in `tidyr` which takes into account JohannesNE's
poignant comment.

You can think of this, as the 'trick' you were referring to in your reply (assuming each consecutive `Monday` and `Sunday` is a pair):

```
df <- as.data.frame(df) # tidyr needs a df object
df <- cbind(pair = rep(1:3, each = 2), df) # the 'trick'!
```

```
  pair   days      dates
1    1 MONDAY 2020-03-02
2    1 SUNDAY 2020-03-08
3    2 MONDAY 2020-03-09
4    2 SUNDAY 2020-03-15
5    3 MONDAY 2020-03-16
6    3 SUNDAY 2020-03-22
```

Now the `tidyr` implementation:

```
library(tidyr)

df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = days, values_from = dates)
```

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
   pair MONDAY     SUNDAY    
  <int> <chr>      <chr>     
1     1 2020-03-02 2020-03-08
2     2 2020-03-09 2020-03-15
3     3 2020-03-16 2020-03-22
```